# Delete element from an array in java

Tags: java

I have an array and I am implementing a priority queue with it. Now, I cam not shift the elements(since only the front pointer has to move).

I tried that by adding null to that array position but it just does not work since I have used `Arrays.sort(arr)`  methods and if I do make the position null, it gives NullPointerException.

Here is how my code looks:

```
public static void remove() {
    //Priorityy x = arr[front];
    arr[front] = null;
    front--;
    //return x;
}

public int compareTo(Priorityy pe) {
    if (this == null || pe == null)
        return 0;
    else {

        if (this.key < pe.key) {
            return 1;
        } else if (this.key > pe.key) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: If you want to remove elements then don't use an array. This is completely the wrong data structure. You are looking for a [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

Comment: @BoristheSpider : I understand, but I wanted to implement an array based Priority queue, like I implemented stacks and other kind of queues with arrays. I was deleting elements there as well, but since compareTo was not used there, it was not a problem. This is just for understanding concepts, not that I am implementing it in real world application but only trying to figure out if there exists  possible way

Comment: In that case your approach is wrong. Removing a element should simply sift everything up, adding another `null` at the end. This should take `O(n)` time (similar to an insertion sort single iteration). Using `Arrays.sort` is certainly not right.

Comment: If you want to delete a certain entry from array, I suggest you to implement `equals()` and `hashcode()` for it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider : Shifting the element would want me to move rear pointer as well, but according to the book,'Samn teach your self Data structures, The rear pointer should always stay at the bottom and not move.

Comment: @DarshanLila: I am sorry, but I did not get how does that change things? I mean I do get the hashCode and check fi elements are equal, but how is that going to help in deleting one?

Comment: You'll be spared with Null Pointer Exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-T:A-int-int-) to get an array without the first element (front) as follows:

```
arr = Arrays.copyOfRange(1, arr.length);
```

Comment: Exacatly what I wanted :D, Thanks a ton :)